# Does the pity timer build up across different summoning banners?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Fire Emblem Heroes always has multiple summoning banners running, and in each banner, your first summon is free.

I know that in each round, when you summon non-5* heroes, the pity timer builds so that in the next round you increase your odds of summoning a 5* hero.

---

I'm wondering if each banner has its own pity timer, meaning I have to keep spending orbs within that same banner for increased odds of getting a 5* hero?

**Example**, pulling 2 rounds of 3* heroes will build the pity timer so I get increased odds of pulling a 5* within the same banner, but the pity timer starts from scratch if I invest into a different banner.

---

Or is it a global pity timer, in that any round I do will increase the odds of me getting a 5* in the next round in ANY banner?

**Example**, I put orbs in Banner 1, but only get 3* units. Then I put orbs into Banner 2, and now I have increased chance of summoning 5* in Banner 2 because my last round in Banner 1 was garbage?

---

I'm just not sure if I should keep summoning within a banner until I get a 5*, or if I can just switch any time I want and still have the pity timer be valid.

Or have I misunderstood how pity timers work fundamentally?

Comment: You should keep summoning in 1 banner as each banner has its own "pity timer" :) Summoning in one will not affect another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each banner tracks this separately. You can see your increased odds in each banner by going to "appearance rates", so you can easily track which banners you have increased odds on.

This increments every time you go a round of five summons without summoning a 5* hero. The appearance rate is increased 0.5% for **each set of five times**.

You can see more information in each banner by going to **Details -> More Key Information about Summoning**

Additionally, if you somehow manage to summon 120 times without getting a 5*, the rate is increased to 100%.